# Increment/Decrement SeekBar Slowly

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a button to get my SeekBar to slowly increment && || decrement to a certain int value (maybe I can only do this with a double?), let's say the progress of the seekbar starts at 0, I want to increment to 50 over about a 5 second period of time. Is this possible in Android?

```
 //  ON SEEKBAR CHANGE
   fill.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            fillProgress = String.valueOf(progress); 
            fillView.setText(fillProgress);

        }
    });

    centerDistribution.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TOAST: ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO fill bucket?
            // IF YES
            // INCREMENT SEEKBAR SLOWLY

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never personally used it for this purpose but you can use an `AsyncTask` to make sure your UI remains responsive during the moving process. Essentially you'll use `AsyncTask` like you were updating a progress bar, but instead of a progress bar you'll be updating the value of the `seekbar` instead. [You'll need to override the entire class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), but the bread and butter will be here:

```
private class AsyncTaskSeekbar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{       
  @Override
  protected void doInBackground(String... params) 
  {
   try 
   {
    int time = 5000;           //5000 ms = 5 seconds  
    int incTime = 5000 / 50;   //we want it to get to 50 after 5 seconds 100ms per Seekbar unit

    for(int i = 0; i < time; i += incTime)
    {
        Thread.sleep(incTime);
        publishProgress(); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
    }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate() 
  {
   seekBar.setProgess(seekBar.getProgess() + 1);
  }
}
```

Of course you'll have to do some things like initialize the AsyncTaskSeekbar, pass in values dynamically, etc. But this should give you a good idea of how to get started.